# Augmented reality on Android: which version of the OS would be needed?

Tags: android, version, augmented-reality

Which version of Android is needed to create a working augmented reality application ?

Answer (score 4):

All that is needed for an augmented reality app is access to the camera's preview data.  This has been available since Android API Level 1 (1.0).  So technically, you can develop an augmented reality app on any version of Android.

See:  [Camera.PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html)